# Why is there a difference between month reputation and total reputation if I'm new here?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Well the title is quite clear.
Why is there a difference between month reputation and total reputation if I'm new here ?
Mathematically that makes no sense : previous reputation $= 0$ thus $0 + x = x$ ! :)

Comment: Interesting.  Several other new users have 1 point more in "all" reputation than they have in "year" reputation.

Comment: The difference can be larger than 1. At first i thought it was some bonus , like being part of other exchange sites or such but it turns out not to be that.

Comment: Here are some meta.SO threads where some difference occured: [Discrepancy between year rep and total rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/discrepancy-between-year-rep-and-total-rep) and
[Discrepancy between year rep and total rep? (another)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110578/discrepancy-between-year-rep-and-total-rep-another) What exactly is the difference in your case?

Comment: @GEdgar: You start off with $1$ reputation, not $0$. I presume this results in the difference you see.

Comment: When I check your reputation [this year](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year&search=mick),  [this month](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month&search=mick) and [total](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=mick), the numbers I see differ by 1. Do you see different values?

Comment: @Martin : Oh but i looked at different places. When i click at ' top 11% this month ' i see a difference around 25.

Comment: Aha found it.
Accepted answers do not count. That explains the difference.
Close thread ?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/183484), total reputation shown in [monthly league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2012-09-01/39261#39261) includes things like downvotes on deleted question.
Monthly reputation does not include such votes. Could this be an explanation in your case?